# Can I redirect my PDF File to my php homepage?

Tags: php, html, pdf, mysqli, tcpdf

Good Day, I've been for some solution to my problem. I used TCPDF-master to generate PDF report. The thing is, after I generate a PDF File, and print. I don't know how to redirect it back to my transaction page. I'm using mysqli, php and html to PDF file. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  Can you provide a minimal yet complete example to illustrate the problem and specifically indicate what is going wrong?

Comment: Do you want to send the generated PDF file back to the client?

Comment: You likely need to think through your user interface. if your PDF file is opening in the same browser window. Either open your PDF in a new window, or perform your redirect after pressing a button to print.

Comment: is it possible to create a back button in PDF file?

Comment: I know for sure that it is possible to create text or button links in a PDF file. I would expect that the documentation of TCPDF-master shows some examples for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can't redirect from your PDF to your site. The best solution is to open the PDF in another tab in the browser, so when the user finish to use the PDF only have to close the PDF tab.

Answer (score 0):

If you must generate a link inside the PDF itself the Writehtml() method on your TCPDF object may help. see this link https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_006/

```
$html = '<a href="whatever">your link text</a>';
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
```